# android webview text selection listener

Tags: android, android-webview

hey all
i am using a webview in my android app. once i select text on a page i know i can use clipboardmanager to "getText()". But is there a listener that polls whenever a new text is selected?
i want to trigger an event everytime a user selects a text.

thanks a lot :)

Comment: refer this link 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503270/tracking-the-selecting-text-in-android-webview/8542992#8542992

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For anyone struggling with the same situation, i found the solution in using android 3.0 api 11 , which has an event handler:

```
ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener mPrimaryChangeListener
       = new ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener() {
   public void onPrimaryClipChanged() {
              // Your code in here 
   }
};
```

Comment: this does not fire on the actual select "event" but on the copy, etc in the action bar -- now, how to override that functionality...??

Comment: Is there any solution for Android-2.2?